# Javascript regex code not working as expected

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript-6

I made a function to break a string to break it into parts.
I read on MDN that by putting regex in parentheses I could refer it later by using `$1` but for some reason my code is not working.
I want this function to return `'url this'` but it is return `'$ 1his'`.

Please Help!

```js
const someFunction = str => {
 return str.replace(/([A-Z]+)/g,('$1'.slice(0,-1).toLowerCase() + ' ' + '$1'.slice(-1).toLowerCase()));
  }
console.log(someFunction('URLThis'))
```

Comment: You're confused. Function arguments are evaluated before the function is called. `'$1'.slice(0,-1)` is just `$`.

Comment: @melpomene So what should I do to reference it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass function in the second parameter to [`string#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

```js
const someFunction = str => {
 return str.replace(/[A-Z]+/g, (match) => {
  return match.slice(0,-1).toLowerCase() + ' ' + match.slice(-1).toLowerCase();
 });
}
console.log(someFunction('URLThis'))
```

Comment: You don't even need the capturing parens there.

Answer (score 1):

You are going to want to use a function as the second parameter for manipulating the result of the replacement. From MDN [String.prototype.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

> Because we want to further transform the result of the match before
>   the final substitution is made, we must use a function. This forces
>   the evaluation of the match prior to the toLowerCase() method. If we
>   had tried to do this using the match without a function, the
>   toLowerCase() would have no effect.
>
> This is because '$&'.toLowerCase() would be evaluated first as a
>   string literal (resulting in the same '$&') before using the
>   characters as a pattern.